# Node.js http.get against squarespace.com site has status code 403

Tags: node.js, squarespace

When I do a simple `http.get` for a URL that goes to a SquareSpace (SS) site I'm getting a 403 message. I know the site is working and that the server can reach it. Here's a simple example against a SS site (not mine, but produces the same issue):

- Show that server can access site:

  `curl http://www.letsmoveschools.org
  This returns all the HTML from the site...`
- Node app

  ```
  var http = require('http');
  var url;

  url = 'http://www.letsmoveschools.org/';

  var req = http.get(url, function(res) {

    res.on('data', function(chunk) {
     //Handle chunk data
    });

    res.on('end', function() {
      // parse xml
      console.log(res.statusCode);
    });

    // or you can pipe the data to a parser
    //res.pipe(dest);

  });

  req.on('error', function(err) {
    // debug error
    console.log('error');
  });
  ```

When I run the node app now `node app.js` it outputs the `403` status code.

I have tried this code with other sites and it works fine, just not against squarespace sites. Any idea of either configuration on SS or something else I need to do in Node?

Comment: Does the response body have any content?  Perhaps something mentioning authentication or use of robots?

Comment: @mscdex thanks for fixing my code. For future reference, what did you do to the code block to make it look proper? I tried several things but wasn't able to get it workin.

Comment: @MartinGiffyD'Souza If you're asking how I came to the solution, I knew that cURL doesn't send many headers by default and that headers were the only difference between the two requests. So I tried setting the headers cURL was sending one by one, until I found the minimal set of headers that worked (in this case, just `User-Agent` was enough).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that the remote server is expecting/requiring a `User-Agent` header and node does not send such headers automatically. Add that and you should get back a 200 response:

```
// ...

url = 'http://www.letsmoveschools.org/';

var opts = require('url').parse(url);
opts.headers = {
  'User-Agent': 'javascript'
};

var req = http.get(opts, function(res) {
// ...
```